# Searching in mongoDb (using mongooseJS) by several criteria

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoose, schema

For example, I've got a Schema

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({

username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
surname: { type: String, required: true },
....
....
```

Is it possible to search for users by name, username, surname simultaneously? I mean, if we input "Paul" - we get an array of users including users with username containing "Paul", name "Paul" and surname< which may contain "Paul".

How to do this using queries in Mongoose(how the construction for this kind of search looks like) Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic syntax around Mongoose queries is nicely [documented](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

And, yes, you can use any number of fields in a search condition. There is a bunch of [logical operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) available to combine your filters with. And for case-insensitive "contains" queries you'd need to use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) like so:

```
var userName = "Paul";
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
User.find({
    $or:
    [
        { "username": { $regex: userName, $options: 'i' } },
        { "name": { $regex: userName, $options: 'i' } },
        { "surname": { $regex: userName, $options: 'i' } }
    ]
},
function (err, docs) {
    /* do something with your results */
});
```

Comment: No worries, that stuff is really basics. ;) Try to work yourself through some tutorials and documentation first!